# set fullcalendar end date on drop, wrong timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to set the end date of an event when dropped into a js fullcalendar.

The end date is 2hours too long, I guess this is a timezone issue as I have CET time, it's UCT + 2 hours. How can I correct this?

I have the following code :

```
eventReceive: function (event){
                    event.allDay = false;
                    event.end = event.start.clone().add(2, 'hours').toDate();
                    console.log(event.start);
                    console.log(event.end);
                    $calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                    console.log(event.end);
                }
```

It outputs the following in the console :

```
2:875 m {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Array[7], _isUTC: true, _offset: 0, _pf: Object…}_ambigZone: true_d: Wed Jul 08 2015 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)_fullCalendar: true_i: Array[7]_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: true_isValid: true_locale: e_offset: 0_pf: Object__proto__: m

2:876 Wed Jul 08 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)

2:878 m {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Array[7], _isUTC: true, _offset: 0, _pf: Object…}_ambigZone: true_d: Wed Jul 08 2015 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)_fullCalendar: true_i: Array[7]_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: true_isValid: true_locale: e_offset: 0_pf: Object__proto__: m
```

Comment: Is this the same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367481/timezone-for-dropped-event-in-fullcalendar

Comment: sounds like it's similar. there is no answer to this question though... if you find one, welcome :)